# I really miss the tab groups addon that I used to use before Firefox Quantum was released. Anyone know if there's a replacement addon in the works?

Tags: tabs, firefox-addon, grouping, organization, firefox-quantum

When Firefox Quantum was released the tab groups addon that I've been using for a long time stopped working.  Is there an addon already out there that provides tab groups that is compatible with Firefox Quantum?  Or is there one in the works?

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic for SO, as it's not directly related to programming tools. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) is the correct site for general software questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [it's been discontinued](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tab-groups-removal) from Firefox officially, couldn't find a compatible addon as yet.